# Not able to get values in dataTable from the managed bean

Tags: java, jsf, datatables

I have two classes one is plain bean and second one acting as managed bean. I am trying to bind the aboutProduct(List) with my datatable. but I am not able to see the values. Please refer the codes.

```
 public class ProductInfoAttributes {

    private String paramName;
    private String paramValue;



    public String getParamName() {
        return paramName;
    }
    public void setParamName(String paramName) {
        this.paramName = paramName;
    }
    public String getParamValue() {
        return paramValue;
    }
    public void setParamValue(String paramValue) {
        this.paramValue = paramValue;
    }
    public ProductInfoAttributes(String paramName, String paramValue) {
        super();
        this.paramName = paramName;
        this.paramValue = paramValue;
    }



}


//------ Managed Bean Class
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller("productInfoBean")
@Scope("session")
public class ProductInfoBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




    List<ProductInfoAttributes> aboutProduct;


    public List<ProductInfoAttributes> getAboutProduct() {
        return aboutProduct;
    }

    public void setAboutProduct(List<ProductInfoAttributes> aboutProduct) {
        this.aboutProduct = aboutProduct;
    }



    public List<ProductInfoAttributes> showDetails() {
        aboutProduct = new ArrayList<ProductInfoAttributes>();
        aboutProduct.add(new ProductInfoAttributes("Host Name", "localhost"));
        aboutProduct.add(new ProductInfoAttributes("Folder", "newfolder"));
        aboutProduct.add(new ProductInfoAttributes("App Server", "JBoss"));

        return aboutProduct;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

/*-----  And Here is my Datatable code.*/

```
<h:dataTable value="#{productInfoBean.showDetails}" var="details">  /*----- my datatable  */
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Feature</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{details.paramName}" rendered="true" />
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Description</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{details.paramValue}" rendered="true" />
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>  /*-----  data table ends.*/
```

Please tell me where I am wrong.
I am not getting values in the datatables.
I am using JSF 1.2

Answer (score 0):

The `showDetails()` method in the `ProductInfoBean` should be called `getShowDetails()`.

Comment: No its not working. even if I am trying to get a value of any variable from the ProductInfoBean (assume myvar with getters and setters) I did not get success. If you want any more explanation plz tell me.

Comment: I am trying to print value in my .xhtm page using <h:outputText value="#{productInfoBean.myvar}" rendered="true" /> any thing wrong in this.. ?

Comment: Therefore, you cannot access the bean. Check twice the bean name. Are you sure it can be defined with `@Controller` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{productInfoBean.showDetails}" var="details">
```

jsf tries to call a method getShowDetails(). Properties defined in managed beans are accessed/changed from jsf pages by calling the corresponding getter and setter methods.

But in your managed bean you don't have that method declared.

You should call getAboutProduct() from your bean, not showDetails(). Alternatively you could change showDetails to getShowDetails(), but putting logic inside a getter is a bad practice, because that getter will be called for each entry inside the DataTable, which means for every entry it will create a new List.

Instead you could call the method showDetails() by using either the @PostConstruct annotation which will call the method for you after the bean is initialized, or you could call it directly from the page like:

```
#{productInfoBean.showDetails()}
```

And then modify this line like this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{productInfoBean.aboutProduct}" var="details">
```

Now it will call the appropriate getter and retrieve your data.